# Can we replace equals, greater than or less than operator in Spring JPA @Query?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring, Spring Boot,JPA and got stuck with one of the requirement.

Below is the query:

```
@Query("Select re from RequiredAccountEntity re where re.debitAccNo= :debitAccNo "
          + "AND re.date<= :toDate AND re.date>= :fromDate AND re.tnxAmt tnxAmtFlag :tnxAmt ") List<RequiredAccountEntity>
          fetchAllData(@Param("debitAccNo") String debitAccNo, @Param("fromDate")
          Date fromDate, @Param("toDate") Date toDate, @Param("tnxAmt") Double tnxAmt,@Param("tnxAmtFlag") String tnxAmtFlag);
```

In this I am trying to replace the "greater than", "less than " or "equal to" operator dynamically based on the request data from the other application.

Please help me or guide me to do this in the right way in Spring Boot JPA.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using simply [repository-query-keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

```
List<RequiredAccountEntity> findByDebitAccNoEqualsAndDateLessThanEqualAndGreaterThanEqualAndTnxAmtEquals(String debitAccNo, Date fromDate, Date toDate, String tnxAmtFlag);
```

Comment: Hahaha, this method name is great :D

Comment: Do we need to override the methods like findByGreaterThan() method in the repository class?

Comment: @Shanu No, you don't. simply add `method sign` as repository is an interface. :V

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like :

```sql
...
where (:tnxAmtFlag = '<' and re.tnxAmt < :tnxAmt)
or (:tnxAmtFlag = '>' and re.tnxAmt > :tnxAmt)
or (:tnxAmtFlag = '=' and re.tnxAmt = :tnxAmt)
...
```

If you need to get all results when no operator is specified, use :

```sql
...
where :tnxAmtFlag is null
or (:tnxAmtFlag = '<' and re.tnxAmt < :tnxAmt)
or (:tnxAmtFlag = '>' and re.tnxAmt > :tnxAmt)
or (:tnxAmtFlag = '=' and re.tnxAmt = :tnxAmt)
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution is working for me. I will test more and update soon..